# Weightage of products used for measuring inflation

Tags: india, inflation

How does the government fix a particular weightage for a particular commodity which is to be used during measurement of inflation?
Is there any specific scientific formula that is to be used?

Comment: What government? Add a tag for your country, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends upon whose calculation one uses, but the most popular indexes are the [Laspeyres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price_index#Paasche_and_Laspeyres_price_indices) and [Fisher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price_index#Fisher_index_and_Marshall.E2.80.93Edgeworth_index) with a trend towards using the Fisher Index exclusively.

In both cases, the weightings are price-quantity products of different time periods and overlap.

In other words, in the Laspeyres calculation, quantities from the initial time period are used with final prices in the denominator and with initial prices in the numerator.

Half of the Fisher index is the Laspeyres.  The other half uses quantities from the final time period with final prices in the denominator and with initial prices in the numerator.

In other words, they are production weighted by four different perspectives combined into one.

### India

Both the [CPI](http://mospi.nic.in/mospi_new/upload/manual_cpi_2010.pdf) and [WPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wholesale_price_index#Calculation) use the Laspeyres index.

Also, in the linked CPI methodology, a discussion of how weighting is determined for some cases is discussed.

Comment: Can u please explain using an example...like how to decide the weightage of petrol and wheat maybe...

Comment: @user3561433 Absolutely, just give me some time...